# What does it mean when someone reports to somebody?

Tags: meaning

I checked "report" and "report to" with the dictionaries and over the Internet. But didn't find any satisfactory meaning matching this example. So it's still nonsense to me.
Here is the example:

> Hi Yury, thanks for the connect! Wanted to reach out as I lead a team
>   that places .NET Developers here in the DC area, we have done work
>   with SuperFlower  in the past in terms of staffing and have a signed
>   agreement by John Smith. Saw there was a .NET role posted on the
>   website, does that report to you? Sophie

So what did she mean by "to report to"?

Comment: When A reports to B, it means that B is a boss, B is a manager over A, B manages A, B controls A.
Taking into account this logics she probably asked me if I posted that .NET role or if I can control that posted message. She probably mean that this .NET role was posted on our corporate website (SuperFlower company website) and I probably a manager responsible for recruiting...

Answer (score 3):

Upon first reading this I thought it might be an incorrect usage of the word. If the author did mean "report to," in this context she is asking whether or not the .NET role is a position to which you are the superior.

Comment: So she waned to know if I'm a boss over the positions performing .NET role -- in other word if .NET developers reports to me?

Comment: @YuryShpakov For example, the vice president reports to the president. So, to whom would the person filling this particular .NET role report?

Comment: When "someone reports to someone" it's clear to me - pretty common usage (boss-subordinate). But I got confused when "something reports to someone". But in this example by "something reports to someone" she actually meant "(someone performing) something reports to someone".

I guess the dictionaries need to be extended with that meaning/usage.

Comment: It’s just a form of metonony...